# copy_to_user not copying data?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

for a project we are reading and writing data from an embedded FPGA on a SoC system. Writing works (for now just 1 byte, but oh well). The read function correctly accesses the FPGA (and gets the correct value) but for some reason the copy_to_user does not copy anything to the user. Running cat on my device doesn't not return anything. I hope somebody can tell me where I'm doing something wrong.

Additional information: We're targeting a Altrera Cyclone V SoC system with a ARMv7 Processor. We're using a buildroot system with kernel 4.3.0 as recommended by Altera.

Code:

```
// Read function is called whenever a read in performed on one of the /dev devices
static ssize_t mydevice_read(struct file *file, char *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *offset) {
  int success = 0;
  u32 read_value32 = 0;

  // Get the device struct out of the miscdev struct
  struct mydevice_dev *dev = container_of(file->private_data, struct mydevice_dev, miscdev);

  // Read data from FPGA
  read_value32 = ioread32(dev->regs);

  pr_info("Data received from FPGA: %d", read_value32);

  success = copy_to_user(buffer, &read_value32, sizeof(read_value32));

  pr_info("%d: %d bytes copied to userspace pointer 0x%p, value: %d!\n", success, sizeof(read_value32), buffer, dev->data_value8);

  // If copy_to_user failed
  if (success != 0) {
    pr_info("Failed to copy current value to userspace!\n");
    return -EFAULT;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output (including kernel messages and debug prints):

```
# insmod mymodule.ko 
[  701.922707] Initializing mymodule module
[  701.926681] Probing for fpga devices...
[  701.931382] Probing successful!
[  701.935429] FPGA successfully initialized!
# echo -n -e \\x81 > /dev/mydevice
# cat /dev/mydevice 
[  721.555795] Data received from FPGA: 129
[  721.559539] 0: 4 bytes copied to userspace pointer 0xbec67c78, value: 129!
```

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Think @pelya is on the right track. Just also noting that your debug print is printing something called `dev->data_value8` not otherwise used in your code snippet (and not `read_value32`).

Comment: Yeah, that's the value I wrote before (locally stored in a struct) so I have a point of comparison, the first debug print should print the value read correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure about `return 0;`? I think this function should return the amount of bytes copied, in your case this should be `return sizeof(read_value32);`

Comment: Yeah, that definitely changed something. cat now returns "\201" which I assume is some form of representation for that byte. But the output seemingly never stops, do you know why?

Comment: This function will be called in a loop, until it will return 0, which means end of stream. So your `cat` command just continuously dumps the same register value over and over. You may wish to read single value using command `head -c 4` instead of `cat`

Comment: You can also check the `offset` value - it will be 0 at the beginning, then it will become 4, 8, 12, 16 and so on. So when `offset != 0`, you do `return 0`

Comment: head -c 4 works, but I'd kinda like it to stop when I have no more data to read. I have addead a simple `if (offset != 0) return 0` to the beginning, but that just stops before the first call. Is there any way cat starts reading with another value than 0?

Comment: Similar functions in Linux kernel are using `simple_read_from_buffer` function - see an example here: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/s390/char/zcore.c?v=2.6.31#L490   the array to read is `filp->private_data` and the amount of bytes to read is `MEMORY_CHUNKS * CHUNK_INFO_SIZE` in that code. So for you that will be `return simple_read_from_buffer(buffer, len, offset, &read_value32, sizeof(read_value32));` and you don't need to call `copy_to_user`. This function also updates `offset`, which we forgot to do here.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I'll try that!